# TKinter: Scrollable Canvas, Expandable Widgets, and Pack

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, scrollable

I am creating a table using Labels laid out as a grid within a Frame.  I'd like to embed this Frame in a scrollable canvas, and I'd like the Labels to expand to fill the horizontal space while maintaining vertical scrolling capability.  To see what I am trying to do, here is my code:

```
class ScrollableTable(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, rows=4, columns=5):
    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns

    Frame.__init__(self, parent, borderwidth=0, background='green')
    self.canvas = Canvas(self, borderwidth=0)
    self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, borderwidth=0, background='black')  
    self.vsb = Scrollbar(parent, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)    
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)            
    self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=TRUE)      
    # This is where I fix the height I want this window to take up         
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set, width=720, height=80)
    self.height = self.canvas.winfo_reqheight()
    self.width = self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth()        

    self._widgets = []        
    for row in range(rows):
        current_row = []
        for column in range(columns):
            label = Label(self.frame, text="N/A", 
                             borderwidth=0, width=5, anchor=W, justify=LEFT)
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='NESW', padx=0.5, pady=0.5)
            current_row.append(label)
        self._widgets.append(current_row)

    self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor='w', tags=self.frame)
    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
    self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onResize)  
    #self.frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=True)  
    self.vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, expand=True)
```

In the above code, the 2nd to last line is commented.  When it is commented out, I get a table that doesn't expand to fill the space, but the scrollbar works.  However, if I uncomment that lines and use the frame.pack approach, the table fills the horizontal space, but I lose scrolling capability.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why I'm losing the ability to scroll - any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *not* call `pack` on the frame, and because of that you'll need to manage the width of the frame manually. Typically you do this by binding to the `<Configure>` event on the canvas. In the bound function, get the width of the canvas, and then use the `itemconfigure` method to set the width of the window object.